# jQuery - catch and override links with target=_blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have legacy pages which have links where `target="_blank"`. On clicking these I'd like to ignore that and run a some JavaScript I have for opening windows.

Is this possible with jQuery, if so what methods/terms should I research?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a[target=_blank]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do what you want here
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kkhNr/1/

Comment: You're welcome. You should upgrade to 1.9.0 , it's just one copy-paste away :D

Comment: We require a lot of testing of any code changes to our application, while it's trivial to replace the one file the time required to retest is substantial. We plan to join the land of the living in an upgrade happening within the next few months. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 8):

Just use event delegation to prevent the links with target="_blank" from working, example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Prevented');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I need to upgrade jQuery. We're running 1.2.6, on was added in 1.7 :) http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: If you cannot upgrade, perhaps you can use the older .live function.

Comment: Thanks Roger, we plan on upgrading in the near future, however the problem I'm trying to address currently is of higher priority. Upgrading will require we run a large test suite to ensure everything still works. Your solution is perfect for people not stuck in the dark ages. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   $('a[target=_blank]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();            
        // Now make a call to your own function
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out that @Roger C's listener is a better solution...if you have any dynamically loaded content on your page (i.e. AJAX or AngularJS single page applications).

This listener listens to the document's clicks and will pickup newly added content without needing to re-add the listener after content changes:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Prevented');
});
```

This listener listens to all selectors found at the time it was called (possibly missing any newly added content):

```
$('a[target=_blank]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Prevented');
});
```